# Как изменить текст файла под vxWorks командами C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, vxworks

Привет всем!

Есть задача: изменить текст файла (стартовый скрипт) под ОС vxWorks (UNIX-based). Файл находится в памяти роутера. Доступа по ftp, tftp нет (не пингуется). Доступ только через консоль. Содержимое файла выводится в консоль командой

```
copy </dir/file
```

Файловая система tffs. Файл можно скопировать в пределах файловой системы, можно создать директорию командой mkdir, можно создать пустые файлы командами copy, cp, creat.

Вопрос: как изменить содержание существующего файла или записать текст в новый. В мануалах найдена вот такая строка:

> This example copies from the console to the file dog, on device /ct0/, until an EOF (default CTRL+D) is typed:
>     -> copy >/ct0/dog

Но в результате из консоли ничего не пишется в файл. Выяснилось, что система понимает команды C и С++, есть команды fopen, fread и т.д. С синтаксисами запутался.

Что нужно ввести, чтобы отредактировать и сохранить файл (или написать)? Точнее как с помощью команд (функций) C/C++ создать файл в определенной директории, записать в него текст и сохранить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось следующим образом:

```
->#include <stdio.h>
->fp = fopen("/dir/filename.txt", w");
new symbol "fp" added to symbol table. fp = 0x1e6f7a4: value = 15936076 = 0xf32a4c
->fputs(example string\n", fp);
value = 0 = 0x0 (*Получилось!!*)
*Проверяем:*
->copy "/dir/filename.txt"
example string
Copy OK:15 bytes copied value = 0 = 0x0
```

Спасибо, Cool!

Comment: Отформатируйте код, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, я не знаком с vxWorks, поэтому могу ответить только по C. Код ниже создает файл filename.txt и пишет в него строку "example string"; если vxWorks понимает синтаксис C, можно попробовать.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("filename.txt", "w");

    if (f != NULL) {
        fputs("example string\n", f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Еще имеет смысл проверить права доступа, если vxWorks - это Unix-подобная система и в ней та же парадигма прав, то может у пользователя просто нет разрешения на запись.